# Assign hostname to a variable in ksh

Tags: ksh, variable, hostname

I am trying to assign the output of `hostname` to a variable and use it in my script. While I was able to get the variable to another logic, when I try to print the variable it doesn't print the variable.

Here is what I am looking to do:

the `hostname` on the server returns `xy29abcd01`.

I want to assign this to a variable and then use it to remove 3rd and 4th characters of the hostname and assign it to another variable.

Here is what I have

```
#!/bin/ksh

print " Get queue manager name"
SERVER="echo `hostname`"
print"$SERVER"
export QMGR=`$SERVER |cut -c1-2,5-10| tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]`

print "Queue manager name $QMGR"
```

And here is the output When I run this:

```
Get queue manager name
./test.sh[13]: printecho xy29abcd01: not found [No such file or directory]
Queue manager name XYABCD01
```

What am I doing wrong here to assigning the SERVER variable. Desired output it

```
xy29abcd01
Queue manager name XYABCD01
```

Comment: use www.shellcheck.net to check your syntax first

Answer (score 4):

Your script has a few issues:

1. The error stems from the `export` line. You are using `$SERVER` as a command, and this command can not be found.  What you'd like to do is to feed the string into `cut`:

   ```
   print $SERVER | cut -c1-2,5-10 | ...
   ```
2. The line `` SERVER="echo `hostname`" `` is better written

   ```
   SERVER=$(hostname)
   ```
3. The `tr` utility takes character ranges, so there's no need to enclose `[:upper:]` or `[:lower:]` in `[ ... ]`. Do, however, enclose them in quotes:

   ```
   tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
   ```

   It's a good habit for the day when you want to use `tr` for things like `*` that the shell will be treating as a globbing pattern otherwise.
4. In general, do use `$( ... )` rather than backticks. It makes the code more readable, they nest easier, and is [better in many other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming).

Answer (score 1):

Create a bash script.

```
OUTPUT="$(hostname)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Run the bash script using `./scriptname.sh`